# How to launch maven filtering from jUnit test?

Tags: java, maven-2, junit, intellij-idea

Situation: I have a class MyController that works with some external WebServices.

```
public class MyController {
    private String integrationWebServiceURL;
}
```

This class web services URL is passed during configuration controller bean in descriptor(**applicationContext.xml**)

```
<bean id="myController"  class="com.mypath.MyController">
    <property name="integrationWebServiceURL" value="${integration.web.service.url}"/>
</bean>
```

The value is dynamic, actual value is stored in a properties file **application.properties**

```
integration.web.service.url=${pom.integration.web.service.url}
```

But it is not the end - the real value is stored in maven project file (**pom.xml**) with filtering=true.

```
<pom.integration.web.service.url>http://mywebservices.com</pom.integration.web.service.url>
```

So, when we use **mvn install test** values from pom.xml are copied to appropriate placeholders in application.properties and then tests of my class works just fine.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext.xml"})
public class MyControllerTest {

}
```

**Question**: I need to launch my test from IDE to be able to play with different settings and to use IDE's debug feature. But if I simple launch this test from IDE without preliminary Maven build - than my web service address will be simply acquired from application.properties and equals "${pom.integration.web.service.url}" (e.g. process of Maven filtering doesn't work before test). How can I adjust Maven, Spring or jUnit to extract my value from pom.xml?

**NOTE**: I know that I can simple set this value explicitly in application.properties or applicationContext.xml files that used by Test-class, but I need extract this values from pom.xml.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, did you tryed M2Eclipse or M2E plugin?

Comment: Why do you need to get the value from the POM?  Or rather, what I really mean is, why is the POM a suitable place to store that information?  I would advise keeping such data in a properties file _outside_ of the deliverable artifact, and accessing it at runtime only.  You can then have a version of the properties file, available on the test classpath only, which is specific for tests.

Comment: @Ralph IntelliJ IDEA is my IDE.

Comment: @Andrew Spencer This values are now in pom.xml. Legacy code, placed here by another developer - and I think that there were some reasons for this. I have no opportunity to change it.

Comment: I think this is a Maven + IntelliJ IDEA question.

Comment: Note that `mvn install` already runs `test` :-)

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Simply run with maven, as in:

```
mvn test
```

Then all should go with filtering of pom variables.
You can have testResources for specific properties files. Or an applicationContext-test.xml.

Comment: I think the OP's need was for the test to work after a clean+build from the IDE (i.e. a non-Maven build).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use an IDE which is Maven-aware and which runs [mvn copy-resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) when the source has to be built. For Eclipse, try [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), for IDEA, the Maven plugin should do this as well.

If that isn't an option for some reason, you can run the target manually, for example in a static code block in common test code (so it's always executed exactly once):

```
static {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "mvn copy-resources" );
    IOUtils.copy( p.getInputStream(), System.out );
    p.waitFor();
}
```